# How to force npm to instanciate only one copy of a dependecy from two different projects

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm

I am a bit frustrated here. I am new to npm and config files. I am trying to create a vue project (although I think it is irrelevant to the problem) with typescript and reuse its code and components.

I have two problems:
1. I get one copy of Vue in the library project and another one in the other project using this library.
2. The type definitions for vue are not included from the lib, but maybe when the first problem resolve, then this one will as well.

I have tried to link the library project with npm link, import with relative paths and build it with vue-cli --traget lib (where Vue is suppose to be externalized), but nothing helped. Maybe I did it wrong. I have looked at other libraries like Buefy, Vuetify, Vue-router, but none of them is using typescript with the vue-property-decorator or calling import 'vue'.

The structure is:
-- some folder
  |--- lib
    |--- vue (package.json)
    |--- Test.vue
    |--- type definitions

|--- project
    |--- vue (package.json)

The error I get is that $propertyA is not defined on Vue (Property or method "$propertyA" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render). When I use String.has it works.
If I use in the library (like all others do) the code below it works:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{msg}} -> {{$propertyA}}</div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Test',
    data: () => ({
        msg: 'TEST'
    })
}
</script>
```

When I use in the library the code below it does NOT work:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{msg}} -> {{$propertyA}}</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
    private msg = 'TEST';
}
</script>
```

The type definitions:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    export interface Vue {
        $propertyA: string;
    }
}

declare global {
    interface String {
        has: (x: string) => boolean;
    }
}
```

What would be the right way to solve it? I think the problem is having two different projects, in which each gets its own copy of Vue and that is why one has $propertyA and the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around and looking at vue-router for inspiration, I managed to get it running. So if anyone has this problem, here is the solution I've found, regarding what to add to the json files of the library:

- Put your declaration file in types/index.d.ts
- tsconfig.json:

```
...
"include": [
  ...  
  "types/index.d.ts"
],
```

- package.json:

```
...
"main": "dist/**Your Lib Name**.common.js", // you can add module etc. for other relevant outputs
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name **Your Lib Name** src/main.ts",
},
"typings": "types/index.d.ts",
"files": [
  "src",
  "dist/*.js",
  "types/*.d.ts"
],
```

- run npm build
- copy folders dist, types and package.json to node_modules/**Your Lib Name** in the project you want to use your library

I think **npm link** does not work because it includes the node_modules folder under the library, resulting in two copies of, in this case, vue, but I am not sure.

Regarding vue, if you want to make your life easier and let typescript generate the declaration files for you, add the following:

- tsconfig.json:

```
...
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": "types_tmp/",
```

- vue.config.js:

```
...
configureWebpack: config => {
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
      if (rule.use) {
        let idx = rule.use.findIndex(w => w.loader === 'thread-loader')
        if (idx !== -1) rule.use.splice(idx, 1)
      }
    })
  }
},
chainWebpack: config => {
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // disable cache (not sure if this is actually useful...)
    config.module.rule("ts").uses.delete("cache-loader");
    config.module.rule("tsx").uses.delete("cache-loader");

    config.module
    .rule('ts')
    .use('ts-loader')
    .loader('ts-loader')
    .tap(opts => {
      opts.transpileOnly = false;
      opts.happyPackMode = false;
      return opts;
    });
  }
}
```

- merge the relevant .d.ts files into types/index.d.ts

Hope it helps someone,